# Can "attempt to apply non-function" be augmented to report function name?

Tags: r

I have a set of functions that are defined in an environment.  Alas, when I then try to invoke a function from this environment, and I mistype it, the error is obscure.

```
h <- environment()
> h$abc <- function() cat("OK\n")
> h$abc()
OK
> h$abcd()
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

Ideally, I would like it to say

```
no function 'abcd()' in environment 'h' in file sourcefile.R:121
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can try using `with` `with(h, abc())#
OK
> with(h, abcd())#
Error in abcd() : could not find function "abcd"`

Comment: for nearest meaning, `with(h,abc)()` avoids accidentally picking up argumens from the environment.  thanks for the help.  I wish R would produce the same error message by default for the `h$abcd` case.